# Computing a complicated expected value

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, stochastic-analysis

I want to compute the following expected value:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_k^K \left(\widetilde{T_k}-\frac{\varepsilon k}{v}\right)^2\right)$$
with $\widetilde{T_k}=\sum_i^k T_i$, the $T_i$ being continuous random variables, that are exponentially distributed (with $\mathbb{E}(T_i)=1/\sigma$, with $\sigma$ a constant) and $v,\varepsilon >0$ constants.

I am quite confused by having these two sums and the product which I don't really know how to deal with:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_k^K \left(\left(\sum_i^k T_i\right)-\frac{\varepsilon k}{v}\right)^2\right] =  \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_k^K \left(\left(\sum_i^k T_i\right)-\frac{\varepsilon k}{v}\right)\cdot\left(\left(\sum_i^k T_i\right)-\frac{\varepsilon k}{v}\right)\right] $$

I know that in general it holds that:
$\mathbb{E}\left( \widetilde{T_k}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}T_i \right) = \mathbb{E}\left(T_1 \right) +\dots +\mathbb{E}\left(T_k \right) = \frac{k}{\sigma}$ but in my case I am not sure if I can use something like that...
I am very gladful for any help!

Comment: Assuming the range of summation is just fixed, you can just expand the sum all the way out: $\sum_k (\sum_i T_i - ck)^2 = \sum_k \left ( \left ( \sum_i \sum_j T_i T_j \right ) - ck \sum_i T_i + c^2 k^2 \right )$. So the nontrivial probability task here is finding $E[T_i T_j]$. After that (and getting $E[T_i]$ but that part is easy), it's algebra.

Comment: Using characteristic function, I got
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k=1}^K \left(\widetilde{T_k}-\frac{\varepsilon k}{v}\right)^2\right)=\frac{K(K+1)}{2\sigma^2}\bigg(\frac{2K+1}{3}\Big(1-\frac{\epsilon\sigma}{v}\Big)^2+1\bigg)$$
If usage of characteristic function is OK in this task, I will post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the exponential variables are also independent. If this is not the case, I believe we cannot answer the question because we need their covariance structure.

By computing the square,using the linearity of the expectation and the independence, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^{K}\bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}T_i T_j + \frac{\epsilon^2 k^2}{v^2} -2\frac{\epsilon k}{v} \sum_{i=1}^{k}T_i\bigg]\bigg] &\overset{\mathrm{lineariy}}{=} \\
\sum_{k=1}^{K}\bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\mathbb{E}[T_i T_j] + \frac{\epsilon^2 k^2}{v^2} -2\frac{\epsilon k}{v} \sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{E}[T_i]\bigg] &\overset{\mathrm{indep.}}{=} \\
\sum_{k=1}^{K}\bigg[ \sum_{i \ne j}\mathbb{E}[T_i]\mathbb{E}[ T_j] + \mathbb{E}[T_{i}^{2}] + \frac{\epsilon^2 k^2}{v^2} -2\frac{\epsilon k}{v} \sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{E}[T_i]\bigg] = \\
\sum_{k=1}^{K} \bigg(\frac{\epsilon^2}{v^2} - \frac{2 \epsilon}{v \sigma}\bigg)k^2 +\frac{(k-1)^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{2}{\sigma^2}= \\
\frac{K(K+1)(2K+1)}{6}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{v^2} - \frac{2 \epsilon}{v \sigma}\bigg) + \frac{K(2-K)}{\sigma^2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice solution (+1). Just one point: at $K=1$
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\left(T-\frac{\varepsilon k}{v}\right)^2\right)=\mathbb{E}\Big(\left(T^2\right)\Big)-\frac{2\epsilon}{v}\mathbb{E}\Big(\left(T\right)\Big)+\frac{\epsilon^2}{v^2}=\frac{2}{\sigma^2}-\frac{2\epsilon}{\sigma v}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{v^2}$$
Your solution gives $\,\,\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sigma^2}-\frac{2\epsilon}{\sigma v}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{v^2}$. The point is that $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[T_i\, T_j]\neq\mathbb{E}[T_i]\mathbb{E}[ T_j]\,\text{at}\, i=j$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you very much for the remark, totally fogot about that. I edted my answer to account for the mistake.

Comment: @finch Thank you very much for your help! You are right, I totally forgot to mention, that the $T_i$ are independent! I would have one question where I quite don't get your computation: in the 4th line I don't see how you get the $\frac{(k-1)^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{2}{\sigma^2}$ out of the 3rd line?

Comment: @putti.123 In the double sum, since $i \ne j$, we have one less term, i.e. we have $k-1$ terms per each sum. Hence $\frac{k-1}{\sigma} \frac{k-1}{\sigma}$. For the expected value of the square of an exponential you can insted use the fact that $\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$

Comment: @finch I see, that makes sense! Thanks!